# Signal App (Chrome extension) fails to import contacts

Tags: android, google-chrome

I'm on OSX Sierra, Chrome Version 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit).  I installed the Signal add-on for Chrome, linked an Android Galaxy 6 to the Signal add-on app, but no contacts show up in the Signal desktop app.

Then, from within the Signal add-on app, I went to `Settings`, and pressed `Import Now`.  That results in the error message:

```
Import failed. Make sure your computer and your phone are connected to the Internet.
```

I noticed someone else ran into this issue and saw a reference to a "key-rate-limit".  It sounds like there possibly is some kind of list of security keys on the server side, and in some way my Chrome add-on has breached a server-side limit.

Does anyone know what's going on?

Thanks.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. This is not a programming question.

Comment: My bad.  If anyone does reach this question, the short answer is that the "import-failure" is a spurious error message; it is triggered when none of your contacts in Signal actually use Signal themselves.